# Metabase Variable Filters for Postgres

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I am running Metabase and PostgresSQL in Docker.

SQL query works fine. But its just **Variable Filter** in Metabase won't activate for my database.

```
select * from 
test_schema."Project" as pj 

where pj."Division" = {{"The Filter"}}
```

Any help here is really appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Note: I have already tried Syncing database and Re-scan fields in the Metabase

Error: Cannot run the query: missing required parameters: #{"\"The Filter\""}

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed.

There is no double quotes needed in the variable filter. Also, it doesnt take spaces. Here is the working query:

```
test_schema."Project" as pj
where pj."Division" = {{Filter}}
```